# Get all the textbox which exists in RectangleShape of Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have around 7 `textboxes` inside a `RectangleShapes` which comes with `Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks` dll which I want to retrieve and apply some validations. I have below code which retrieves all the `textboxes` from the form which is not what's expected. Does anyone know how to retrieve only those `textboxes` which are inside a `RectangleShape`?

```
Dim empty = Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)().Where(Function(txt) txt.Text.Length = 0)
'empty will fetch all the textboxes inside form'
If empty.Any Then
    MessageBox.Show("Some of the fields are empty.!")
    Exit Sub
End If
```

I tried this `Me.RectangleShape1.Controls` which is not valid but I don't have any other idea to fetch this!!

Any suggestions or ideas are welcome. Below is the image where a `textbox` for **Add Service** is present which is outside `RectangleShape1`

[image]

Comment: You're going to have to actually test the bounds of each textbox to determine whether it's within the bounds of the rectangle.

Comment: @jmcilhinney and how I can do that?

Comment: I would place a `Panel` control inside of the `RectangeShape1`. Then you can test agains the `Panel.Controls` collection.

Comment: or just place in the panel and set border, avoding any shape at alll (because it's vb pack, not part of .net framework, if I'm not wrong, and there is some problems about deploying with app). Anyway, I always avoid shapes.

Comment: Thank you @nelek for your time and help!

Comment: no problem. cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because shapes doesn't have Controls You have to check position of each textbox are they inside rectangle or not. It is little messy but it will work.

This is my solution :

```
Dim txts As New List(Of TextBox)
Dim x1 = RectangleShape1.Left
Dim y1 = RectangleShape1.Top
Dim x2 = RectangleShape1.Left + RectangleShape1.ClientRectangle.Width
Dim y2 = RectangleShape1.Top + RectangleShape1.ClientRectangle.Height
For Each Control In Me.Controls
  If TypeOf Control Is TextBox Then
    Dim txt As TextBox = Control
    Dim tx = txt.Left, ty = txt.Top
    If tx >= x1 And tx <= x2 And ty >= y1 And ty <= y2 Then
       txts.Add(txt)
    End If
  End If
Next
Dim empty = txts.Where(Function(txt) txt.Text.Length = 0)
If empty.Any Then MsgBox("Some field(s) are empty")
```

Comment: Well Thank you @nelek.. Am accepting this as answer but I have followed different approach and I will post it as answer and this approach works as I have tested it..

Comment: You're welcome. There is many ways by `.Tag` or `.Name` or Your answer as well, to.

Answer (score 3):

Well I found that there is a property called `AccessibleDescription` for each `textbox` and I have set a value for that and while retrieving I just did as below:

```
Dim empty = Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)().Where(Function(txt) txt.Text.Length = 0 
And txt.AccessibleDescription = "JobControls")
If empty.Any Then
     MessageBox.Show("Some of the fields are empty.!")
     Exit Sub
End If
```

Hope someone finds it useful

Comment: of You can use `TextBox1.Tag="JobControls"`, too. There is many ways :)

Comment: Yep!! Agreed @nelek.. :)